# Partial string replacement using pandas replace

Tags: python, pandas

```
               a1   a2      a3                  v_Zones                  l_season  inlier
58             0  21393.0 -34.0247  ...          7_VII                    163    True
999            0  61028.0 -31.9992  ...          44_VI                    135    True
15             0  20296.0 -30.1956  ...           4_Vn                    226    True
746            0  55236.0 -33.1020  ...           2_VI                    174    True
1000           0  61032.0 -32.1942  ...          20_Vc                    158    True
```

In the dataframe above, I want to replace the strings in `v_Zones` column based on following logic:

- Any string ending in `Vn` should end with `VI` instead
- Any string ending in `Vc` should end with `V` instead

I tried using pandas `replace` command, but not sure how to partially replace a string based on regex. Result should look like this:

```
              a1   a2      a3                  v_Zones                  l_season  inlier
58             0  21393.0 -34.0247  ...          7_VII                    163    True
999            0  61028.0 -31.9992  ...          44_VI                    135    True
15             0  20296.0 -30.1956  ...           4_VI                    226    True
746            0  55236.0 -33.1020  ...           2_VI                    174    True
1000           0  61032.0 -32.1942  ...          20_V                     158    True
```

Comment: You say you "tried using pandas replace command", can you clarify by providing a [mcve] with what you've tried and the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a simple `replace`:

```
 df['V_Zones'] = df.v_Zones.replace({'Vn$':'VI', 'Vc$':'V'}, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
df['V_Zones']=df['V_Zones'].str.replace('Vn$','VI').replace('Vc$','V')
```